# Cannot make a <string, int> pair with char* as string in C++

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I'm trying to have a map of `<string, int>`. I am trying to put individual characters of a given string as the key of the key value pair. However, I am running into this error:

```
Line 7: no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::find(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&)'
```

This is my code:

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    unordered_map<string, int> map;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (map.find(s[i]) == map.end()) {
            count++;
            map.insert(make_pair<string, int>(s[i], 1));
        } else {
            map.clear();
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

I think the error is because s[i] becomes a char* and so I cannot do make_pair since char* and string are different types.

I have tried to get around this by doing:

```
string temp(s[i]); // Try to create a string from the char* and pass it into the make_pair function
```

However, I still get the same error.

Comment: `s[i]` is not a `char*`, it is simply a `char`.

Comment: `s[i]` is a `char`. You can’t construct a `std::string` with just a `char`.

Comment: Do you want a `map` of a single character as the key or multiple characters?

Answer (score 2):

> I think the error is because s[i] becomes a char* and so I cannot do make_pair since char* and string are different types.

No, [what `s[i]` returns](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is just a single `char` (more precisely, a `char&` reference), which can't be converted to a `std::string` directly.  To construct a `std::string` from a `char`, you need to use a different constructor of `std::string`, i.e:

[`basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

For example:

```
map.insert(make_pair<string, int>(string(1, s[i]), 1));
```

Or:

```
map.insert(make_pair<string, int>({1, s[i]}, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string::operator[]` returns a (reference to a) single `char`, not a `char*` pointer.  You can't construct a `std::string` from just a `char`, which is why are you getting an error.  To construct a `std::string` from a `char`, you need to use one of the following constructors:

```
basic_string(size_type count, CharT ch, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

```
basic_string(const CharT* s, size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

For example:

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    unordered_map<string, int> map;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        string key(1, s[i]); // <-- here
        // or: string key(&s[i], 1);
        if (map.find(key) == map.end()) {
            count++;
            map.insert(make_pair(key, 1));
        } else {
            map.clear();
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Otherwise, change your `std::unordered_map` keys to `char` instead, since that is what you are really using:

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    unordered_map<char, int> map; // <-- here
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char key = s[i];
        if (map.find(key) == map.end()) {
            count++;
            map.insert(make_pair(key, 1));
        } else {
            map.clear();
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

However, you are not actually using the `second` value of the mapped `pair`s at all, so you don't really need the `std::unordered_map` at all, it is just wasted overhead.  Consider using a `std::set` instead:

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    set<char> chars;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // set::insert() return true if inserted, false if duplicate
        if (chars.insert(s[i]).second) {
            count++;
        } else {
            chars.clear();
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```